# Code inside dataTaskWithRequest not executing - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsurlsession

I have an app where I download some data into table view which is working fine and then, I click on 1 cell to download images related to that cell using the url that I downloaded in the previous step. But, the problem is that code inside dataTaskWithRequest is not running.
Here is my code:

```
    func downloadImage(urlString: String) {



        let config: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)

        let session1: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        //let session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        //        request.timeoutInterval = 15

        print(request)

        let newtask = session1.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (let data, let response, let error) in

            print(data, response, error)

            print("Any")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                print("Any")

            })
        })

        newtask.resume()

        print("Any")
 }
```

*request* is printed in the log and the last *"Any"* is also printed but no other print statement is executed.

Is it because of the previous NSUrlSession or anything?

Comment: Where do you call `downloadImage(urlString:)`?

Comment: on didSelectRowatIndexPath

Comment: I've just tested your code and executes all of the prints. Can you try to call it in some other place and see if it works?

Comment: it will work alone but I first download some entries into tableview which also requires session and then i select 1 cell to download its images and then code doesnt execute. This is what I think.

Comment: Have you tried using the same NSURLSession instance?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: @fiks So, the problem was that "completionHandler" doesn't really execute after the dataTaskWithRequest() is complete. It executes before. Didn't know that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117680/discussion-between-fiks-and-karanveer-singh).

Comment: Be sure you keep the session around for the life of your app, not just for the duration of that method.  Besides being wasteful of memory, there's a good chance that the session will invalidate the tasks when the last reference to the session gets released, in which case requests will never finish.